# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64: from a library jar imported with Maven

Tags: java, maven, apache-commons

I've made a simple library jar that consists of this single class:

```
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;

public class NiceEncoder {
    public static String encode(String first, String second) {
        String encoded = new String(Base64.encodeBase64((first + ":" + second).getBytes()));
        return encoded;
    }
}
```

It has this `pom.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>base64tester</groupId>
    <artifactId>base64tester</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
            <version>1.6</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Then I package it into a `jar` and install it in local maven repository:

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=/home/base64tester-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar         -DgroupId=base64tester -DartifactId=base64tester -Dversion=1.0-SNAPSHOT -Dpackaging=jar
```

Then I import it in another project like this:

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>base64tester</groupId>
            <artifactId>base64tester</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

and try running this code:

```
public class TestNiceEncoder  {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
        String first = "some word";
        String second = "other word";
        System.out.println(NiceEncoder.encode(first, second));
    }
}
```

I get the `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64` error.

Why? How do I fix it other than importing the `commons-codec` inside the project with the `TestNiceEncoder` class? How do I make it so everyone who has the `base64tester.jar` can run it with no errors or additional actions?

**EDIT**: It's the same thing with other dependencies in `base64tester` project. Got it to use `JSoup` library and then if the method using it gets called from outside project, there's exception:

In project B:

```
public class TestNiceEncoder  {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
     String first = "some word";
        String second = "other word";
       // System.out.println(NiceEncoder.encode(first, second));
        System.out.println(NiceEncoder.getRedditTitle()); //jsoup error here
    }
}
```

In project A (base64tester):

```
public class NiceEncoder {
    public static String encode(String first, String second) {
        String encoded = new String(Base64.encodeBase64((first + ":" + second).getBytes()));
        return encoded;
    }

    public static String getRedditTitle()  {
        try {
            Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://reddit.com/").get();
            String title = doc.title();
            System.out.println("title: " + title);
            return title;
        }
        catch (Exception e)  {
            System.out.println("Couldn't open URL");
            return "";
        }
    }
}
```

```
 <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
            <version>1.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jsoup/jsoup -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
            <version>1.13.1</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
```

error is this one:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jsoup/Jsoup
```

Comment: You don't use the command line?  No command line - you need those Build things?  The dude has been having me do this (**Java**) 5 years now...  I haven't used a `POM.xml` (or `mvn`) yet.  When you compile using `javac` you just add those (`.jar` files) to the **CLASSPATH** `Environment Variable` - on **UNIX** or **Windows**...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This step

> Then I package it into a jar and install it in local maven repository

require you to specify pom.xml file, otherwise one is generated, but without dependency info

Something like (of course you need to adjust path to pom.xml)

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=/home/base64tester-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar -DpomFile=/home/pom.xml
```

read more in [official docs](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-install-plugin/install-file-mojo.html#pomFile).

Alternatively you can declare explicit dependency on commons-codec in your downstream project (where you're consuming your jar)

Side note, JDK8 already includes support for base64 codec, [see here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.html) - so maybe you can use it directly without any extra jars on classpath

Comment: Even better, do not use install-file at all, simply run "mvn install" from the root directory of your project will install your jar and the associated pom.

Comment: Thank you, it worked! Thanks a lot, really. Spent like hours trying to find solution.

Answer (score 0):

The dependencies package of Base64Tester are not included in jar file. You should use mvn instal from Base64Test project